# Using T4 to create HTML email body in VS2010

Tags: html, email, templates, dynamic, t4

I am new to .NET text transformation and I am trying to use t4 to generate dynamic email body.

So, to give you an example, I have routine that is building a some string as below. how would I  convert this into t4 template instead of StringBuilder string. Will it be a run-time template or design-time template?

```
private string BuildClosingContents(string legalBrand, string legalPhone, 
                                    string legalURL, string transText, string instructText, MyMail.Setting emailConfig)
{
    StringBuilder sbHTML = new StringBuilder();
    sbHTML.AppendLine("<div id=\"closingText\">");
    if (emailConfig.Mode == "Q")
    {
        sbHTML.AppendLine("Please call me on " + legalPhone + " and we will arrange ");
        sbHTML.AppendLine("everything for you. Please have your ticket details to hand ");
        sbHTML.AppendLine("and your " + instructText + " will be required. In the meantime if you have any questions ");
        sbHTML.AppendLine("please do not hesitate to call me.");
        sbHTML.AppendLine("<br /><br />");
    }
    else
    {
        sbHTML.AppendLine("If you have any queries relating to your quote " + transText + " please do not hesitate ");
        sbHTML.AppendLine("to contact your conveyancer or me.");
        sbHTML.AppendLine("<br /><br />");
    }

    // Signature + branding
    sbHTML.AppendLine("Yours sincerely");
    sbHTML.AppendLine("<br />");
    sbHTML.AppendLine("<img src=\"" + legalURL + "/images/agent_sign.jpg\" width=\"80\" height=\"74\" alt=\"\"><br />");
    //sbHTML.AppendLine(legalBrand + " Services<br />");
    sbHTML.AppendLine("</div>");

    // Return the closing content
    return sbHTML.ToString();
}
```

What are the best ways to take these simillar helper text routines outside from application core logic and build a flexiable html strings for email body via t4 template file - Thanks

Comment: What is your question?  We're hardly going to create the T4 template for you.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to read this. as I am new to T4, if someone can point me to right direction via link/article or blog where someone has arleady done something similar would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple example would be:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
The first string is <#= this.FirstString #>.
<# if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.SecondString)) { #>The second string is <#= this.SecondString #>.<# } #>
<#+ 

public string FirstString { get; set; }
public string SecondString { get; set; }

#>
```

Assuming the file is named MyTemplate.tt, then it can be used like:

```
var template = new MyTemplate() {
    FirstString = "Test"
};

var text = template.TransformText();
```

A good tutorial can be found [here](http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/text-template-transformation-toolkit/).

Comment: I'd be inclined to use <#@ parameter #> directives to specify the parameters, e.g. 

<#@ parameter name='legalBrand' type='System.String' #>

Comment: Thanks Gareth - Can you pass a strongly type class to a run-time template?

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you'd use a runtime (or preprocessed) template, as that's the only kind that can be incorporated in your application.  By contrast, design-time execute inside Visual Studio.